# MySQL: How to design table for conversion (e.g. dress sizes)?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

A size "2" dress size in the US is a size "6" in the UK.

How can I model this in a table (or series of tables) in such a way that I can correlate the US 2 with the UK 6? One possible way is to do a table with columns like this:

- id (PK)
- uk
- us

The problem with the design is that I couldn't easily get a list of all dress sizes for a given 2 letter country code (e.g. "us") since that information is a column name.

Also, I want to be able to know whether or not one dress size is larger or smaller than another. I can't rely on the numerical values being higher or lower to determine that apparently since, for example, Russia's size "56" is smaller than its size "24". See:

[image]

Comment: You might have (size_id*,sml,country_iso,size) and form a surrogate pk on size_id, or perhaps form a pk on (size_id,country_iso) or store sml and size_id as a separate table and use size_id as the fk

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is there any application in front that might help you to solve this problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase - I showed what I was planning on doing, then I realized that having the country codes as column names creates some possible problems for me in the long run

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid represents one size **category** (dresses - there exist other size categories like shoes, jeans, bras, whatever.)

Then there are the columns in your grid, which we can call **regions** a name that matches USA, UK/AU/NZ, etc. perfectly, but also includes S-M-L which is not really a "region".

Then there are the rows in your grid representing each one **size** of the given category.

At last there are the cells in your grid, we could call **regional sizes**.

Makes four tables:

```
categories

id | category
---+------------
C1 | dress sizes
C2 | shoe sizes
```

```
regions

id | region
---+--------------
R1 | S, M, L, etc.
R2 | USA
R3 | UK, AU, NZ
```

```
sizes

id | id_category | sortkey
---+-------------+--------
S1 | C1          | 1
S2 | C1          | 2
S3 | C1          | 3
```

```
regional_sizes

id   | sizes | id_region | size
-----+-------------------+-----
RS1  | S1    | R1        | S
RS2  | S1    | R2        | 2
RS3  | S1    | R3        | 6
RS4  | S2    | R1        | S
RS5  | S2    | R2        | 4
RS5  | S2    | R3        | 8
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm digesting this. It looks right, but I need to need to also see if this works for bra cup sizes (as it turns out, there are some weird things happening in there --  some cup sizes convert to more two cup sizes in other regions ...)

Comment: For example, a US cup size B is a cup size A or B in Australia.